# Google Script when taking time from sheets adds +1 minute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time

```
 var pickupTimeOld = wysylka.getRange("C5").getValue()
 var pickupTime = Utilities.formatDate(pickupTimeOld, "GMT+1",  'HH:mm')
```

I am facing an issue while taking the value from google sheets which is for example 9:50:00, it's changing the time to 09:26. I can not find where it subtracts 24 minutes, as from the code everything is fine. Is ther eany possibilty that the confiuguration of google sheets make that issue? What can be reason of this substract.

Screen of formating in google sheets: [image]

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Your spreadsheet timezone, your script timezone(in appsscript.json)

Comment: If you have a formula like `=now()` in the cell then it will not change unless there is some other change or edit in the spreadsheet so the time that you read from that cell could be greatly different from real time if there has been no activity in the spreadsheet.   If you want to get the current time in a script just use new Date();  So again we can't tell what the formula is unless you tell us.  So if you can't provide a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem then this is just a big waste of our time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var wysylka = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var pickupTimeOld = wysylka.getRange("C5").getDisplayValue();
var tz = Session.getTimeZone(); // or SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
var pickupTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today + ' ' + pickupTimeOld), tz, 'HH:mm');
```

Probably in your case it makes sense to define `today` about this way:

```
var today = wysylka.getRange("B5").getDisplayValue()
```

Comment: Thanks, that solve the issue. I am still wondering why there was a subtract upon getRange.getValue(); but your code works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it has to do with antic dates around 1900s for exotic countries like Russia or Poland. See my comments to @doubleunary's answer

Comment: Hmm... the screenshot shows a date of 8 December 2021 that probably goes with the time value. I think that the offset evaluation should be based on that date rather than the current date. When using the current date, `pickupTime` will start reflecting daylight saving time next summer, so the result may then be off by one hour (assuming that the timezone of the script project is EET/EEST or another timezone that observes DST). You may also want to use the spreadsheet's timezone as indicated by your comment in line 3.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are that the issue is caused by your code not observing the date component of the datetime value you want to present as HH:mm.

Your code gets a datetime value from the spreadsheet, but based on the screenshot, it looks like that datetime value only has a time component. That means that the *date component will default to the spreadsheet epoch*, i.e., 30 December 1899. Timezone offsets used to be pretty weird in 1899, so if you omit the date component, you may get surprising results.

Even today, not all timezones are whole hours — there are :30 and :45 offsets in the world in places like Canada, Australia, New Zealand, India, Iran, Afghanistan and Nepal. Dublin Mean Time used to be UTC-00:25:21 and Bombay Time used to be UTC+04:51. Malaya and Singapore used UTC+07:20 as daylight saving time until 1941. And so on.

JavaScript dates are always in UTC, but when you are presenting them, it uses the date's timezone and [zoneinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) to determine the offset to use *on the particular date* that the date object reflects in the timezone of the *runtime environment*.

In Google Apps Script, certain properties of the runtime environment are set by the script project. The script project has a timezone of its own, separately from the hosting spreadsheet, and these two timezones may differ. That is why it is important to use `Utilities.formatDate()` and the *spreadsheet's timezone* when presenting a datetime value to the user.

Your code assumes the `GMT+1` timezone, which may be different from the timezone of the spreadsheet. Most likely, your timezone is `EET` rather than `GMT+1`. These two are not the same thing. Currently the most important difference is that `EET` observes daylight saving time (`EEST`) while `GMT+1` does not. It is possible that in the year 1899 there were other differences as well, which may explain the 24-minute discrepancy you describe.

To get the time value as it shows in the spreadsheet, you need to include the date component, and format the resulting datetime in the timezone of the spreadsheet, like this:

```
  const dateString = wysylka.getRange('B5').getDisplayValue().replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/, '20$3-$2-$1 ');
  const timeString = wysylka.getRange('C5').getDisplayValue();
  const datetime = new Date(dateString + timeString);
  const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const pickupTimeString = Utilities.formatDate(datetime, timezone, 'HH:mm');
```

You may also want to check that your spreadsheet's **File > Settings > Time zone** is set correctly. Note that changing the timezone will change the presentation of datetime values in the spreadsheet, so they may need correction after you change the timezone.

Comment: But how does a timezone issue cause a 24 minute error.  Timezones add or subtract hours?

Comment: @Cooper by default there can be dates around of year 1900 and for Eastern Europe, at least, it can get pretty fancy time offsets. Right now I'm getting from `9:50:00` --> `Sat Dec 30 1899 02:19:43 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`. Go figure.

Comment: @Cooper proof: https://imgur.com/x7OBVu6.png

Comment: The Time zone is set up correctly. It is GMT +1. But the time zone should not affect the minute's parts I think.